# How Can i Store more Than One Fields in List View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

In my view i have 3 edit text and 3 button say add,remove,save.

1. While pressing Add Button i want to Store these 3 fields values into my List View.
2. Pressing Remove i want to remove these three fields from List View.
3. while pressing Save i want to Save whole Data's in List View in-to my Local database.

Please Tell me How can i create a List-View to Store 3 Values. And is that Possible to Create Heading For List View?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a *Header* for your list view by simply:

```
list.addHeaderView(headerView)
```

But ListView is a very complex view so if you have only a few elements (e.g. 3) it is advised to dynamically add the views (see [Google IO presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=40m45s) last minutes)

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list view with 3 subviews in each item. To do this:

1. create a class (a container) for the 3 objects you want to show in an item
2. keep a list/array of those objects you want displayed in the list view
3. implement your own [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)
4. create the adapter with the array/list of the stored objects
5. override the adapter's [`getView:`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method - inflate a view (probably with 3 subviews) for the 3 values you want to display

When you touch "Add" create one object for the 3 values and add it to the array of objects. You'll have to deal with the adapter's items update.

Comment: Looks Like Complicated :)...is there any sample Tutorial or Reference Links are Available..??

Comment: I think the first result from google (for "android listview custom adapter") http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429 doesn't look bad.

Answer (score 0):

This code will bind your data with a listview. You will need an xml file (R.layout.itemlistviewselectform) with the views that you want for each item.

In this code :
lv is your listview.

listItems your data, in my case an ArrayList of HashMap with two key : name and description.

The 4th parameter is the TextView IDs that will receive the name and description.

```
SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listItems, R.layout.itemlistviewselectform, new String[] {"name", "description"}, new int[] {R.id.lvftitle, R.id.lvfdesc});
lv.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```